# Join: three tables and a or condition

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-match-all

I think I should know this somehow, especially after reading a lot of questions and answers regarding "The condition must go into the ON clause, not in the WHERE clause". However, I am still lost.

I have three tables, and I join them normally with LEFT (OUTER) joins. The joined tables looks like this (retty standard):

```
task_id task_questions_taskId   taskQuestions_questionId    question_id
1         1                     5                           5
1         1                     8                           8
2         2                     8                           8
```

```
SELECT `t`.`id` AS `task_id` , 
       `task_questions`.`taskId` AS `task_questions_taskId` ,
       `task_questions`.`questionId` AS `task_questions_questionId` , 
       questions.id AS question_id
FROM `task` `t`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `task_questions` `task_questions` 
    ON ( `task_questions`.`taskId` = `t`.`id` )
LEFT OUTER JOIN `question` `questions` 
    ON ( `task_questions`.`questionId` = `questions`.`id` )
```

This is the standard query to get all the records. (It's taken from Yii; I actually want to to this with Active Record, but can't even get plain SQL right).

And now I want to get ONLY those tasks that have the question_id 2 AND 8 (e.g)
So if a task has not both of those question.ids, I don't want it in the result set.
In this case, the task could have other question_ids, too. Although it would be interesting to see how the query would look if it should return only those that have exactly those 2 (or any other set).
It's easy to get all the tasks that have one question, with WHERE question.id = 2,
but an AND in the WHERE clause leads to an empty result.

Comment: check this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147571/mysql-select-having-multiple-n-to-ns/7147697#7147697

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WHERE clause can only apply conditions to one row at a time.  But your questions of different id occur on different rows.  How to solve this?  Join both rows onto one row using a **self-join**.

Here's an example:

```
SELECT t.`id` AS `task_id`, ...
FROM `task` AS t
INNER JOIN `task_questions` AS tq2 ON ( tq2.`taskId` = t.`id` )
INNER JOIN `questions` AS q2 ON ( tq2.`questionId` = q2.`id` )
INNER JOIN `task_questions` AS tq8 ON ( tq8.`taskId` = t.`id` )
INNER JOIN `questions` AS q8 ON ( tq8.`questionId` = q8.`id` )
WHERE q2.`id` = 2 AND q8.`id` = 8
```

Another solution is to find the tasks that have questions 2 **OR** 8, and then use GROUP BY and HAVING to filter by groups that have exactly two of those.

```
SELECT t.`id` AS `task_id`, ...
FROM `task` AS t
INNER JOIN `task_questions` AS tq ON ( tq.`taskId` = t.`id` )
INNER JOIN `questions` AS q ON ( tq.`questionId` = q.`id` )
WHERE tq.`questionId` IN (2, 8)
GROUP BY t.`id`
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT q.`id`) = 2
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great. It works perfectly. I favour the second version; I could even translate it quite quickly in Yii's Active Record.

Comment: Can you please help me into this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61745432/sql-join-three-table-with-where-clause-giving-extra-results

Comment: @TheCurious, sorry, I agree with the other comments. You haven't provided enough information in that question for anyone to answer. I suspect your attempts to simplify the question has removed some crucial information about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this even with out using and 
... where question.id IN (2,8)

Answer (score 0):

Use `IN`:

```
SELECT `t`.`id` AS `task_id` , 
       `task_questions`.`taskId` AS `task_questions_taskId` ,
       `task_questions`.`questionId` AS `task_questions_questionId` , 
       questions.id AS question_id
FROM `task` `t`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `task_questions` `task_questions` 
    ON ( `task_questions`.`taskId` = `t`.`id`)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `question` `questions` 
    ON ( `task_questions`.`questionId` = `questions`.`id` )
WHERE  `task_questions`.`questionId` IN (2, 8)
```

Comment: Thx, yeah that kind of works - but it actually returns me all the records that have at least one of these question.ids. Is it possible to get only those records that have exactly question.id 2 and question.id 8?

Comment: That have **only 2 and 8**? Or have both 2 and 8 but can have others?

Comment: Good that you mention it; it came to my mind, too. In this case, they could have other question_ids, too. (although it would be interesting how it's done if it's exactly those). Important is to exclude those that don't have both of them.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
SELECT `t`.`id` AS `task_id` , 
       `task_questions`.`taskId` AS `task_questions_taskId` ,
       `task_questions`.`questionId` AS `task_questions_questionId` , 
       questions.id AS question_id
FROM `task` `t`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `task_questions` `task_questions` 
    ON ( `task_questions`.`taskId` = `t`.`id` )
LEFT OUTER JOIN `question` `questions` 
    ON ( `task_questions`.`questionId` = `questions`.`id` )
WHERE  questions.id in (2,8)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not looking for AND, you're looking for OR, or an IN:

```
WHERE `questions`.`id` IN (2,8) -- grab everything in the parens.
```

Or

```
WHERE `questions`.`id` = 2 OR -- grab each item individually
      `questions`.`id` = 8
```

If you use `AND` that would mean the ID would have to be 8 and 2 at the same time. Bad deal.

Comment: Thx, yeah that kind of works - but it actually returns me all the records that have at least one of these question.id. Is it possible to get only those records that have exactly question.id 2 and question.id 8?